# Cannot create a button in a draggable list

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an ng-nestable div and inside that there is a simple button that has an ng-click event hooked up to it. When I click on that button it doesn't register the click but rather starts the drag and drop process.

Here is my HTML Code,

```
 <div class="col-sm-1 text-right"><button ng-click="fnEditHomeSlider({{$item.SliderID}})" class="btn btn-blue btn-sm" nestable-button><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give us some html code from your view ?

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: Is your code something like, try it, Hope it could also matches your need or give us your code

1.) Create a custom directive

```
 myApp.directive('nestableButton', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            $(element).on("mousedown", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });
            $(element).on("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                window.location = $(this).attr("href"); //if you want your URL to update
                return false;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

2.) In HTML

```
<a href="#" nestable-button><i class="fa fa-trash-o right"></i></a>
<a href="#" nestable-button><i class="fa fa-pencil right"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lokesh Kakran is right about this.

And here is live demo project about your solution.

demo : http://pathik.linedeer.com/ng-nestable/

code : https://github.com/pathikdevani/ng-nestable/blob/gh-pages/index.html